# ¿Cómo leer una cantidad de datos o líneas específicas en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, archivo

Tengo un archivo `.lis` , `.txt` o `.csv` y necesito tomar de éste solo una cantidad de datos o líneas y omitir los demás datos, que solo me tome los datos que están entre esas líneas  o palabras  deseadas; o mejor dicho ¿cómo identifico la palabra o línea y que a partir de esta me muestre las lineas o los datos hasta otra palabra o linea donde va terminar?

Hasta la momento solo he podido leer el archivo con este código:

```
abrir = open('clase1.lis','r')
while True:
      linea = abrir.readline()
      if not linea: break
      print linea
```

Otra forma que había intentado era:

```
abrir = open('clase1.lis','r')
for q in abrir:
    print q
```

Y otras más que lo que hacen es mostrarme todo el archivo o imprimirme todos los datos en pantalla. Pero como lo dije anteriormente solo necesito un bloque de ese archivo. El archivo es muy grande.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el criterio para seleccionar las líneas?

Comment: si te refieres por que quiero seleccionar las lineas, es por que dentro de esas lineas hay unos datos específicos que deseo trabajar y luego graficar pero solo me importan esos datos y si no es esa la pregunta no te entendí

Comment: En todo caso, es mejor si añades un ejemplo del archivo que estas leyendo

Comment: Si lo que quieres es buscar información dentro del texto, quizás sería interesante usar un *parser*. Prueba a mirar *pyparsing*, que es sencillo y potente.

Comment: Si te sirvió alguna respuesta puedes marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 7):

Si el archivo es grande te conviene leerlo línea por línea en vez de cargar todo el archivo en memoria. Por ejemplo con el siguiente `archivo.txt`:

```
--------------------------
Hola me llamo Cesar
Soy de Lima
Me gusta Python
--------------------------
Hola me llamo Juan
Yo no soy de Lima
Odio Python
--------------------------
Hola me llamo Jose
Vivo cerca a Lima
Nunca he usado Python
--------------------------
```

Y buscando la palabre clave `Lima`, puedes obtener todas las líneas donde se cumpla esa condición:

```
palabra = 'Lima'
ocurrencias = []
with open('archivo.txt') as lineas:
    for linea in lineas:
        if palabra in linea:
            ocurrencias.append(linea)
print ocurrencias
```

O algo mas compacto usando `filter`:

```
palabra = 'Lima'
ocurrencias = filter(lambda line: palabra in line, open('archivo.txt').readlines())
print ocurrencias
```

Para ambos casos el resultado será una lista con las líneas encontradas:

```
['Soy de Lima\n', 'Yo no soy de Lima\n', 'Vivo cerca a Lima\n']
```

Comment: muchas gracias Cesar pero no es solo seleccionar las lineas donde están las palabras claves es leer el archivo y imprimir solo desde donde aparece la palabra o  linea hasta otro linea o palabra seria como tomar un fragmento del archivo pero de todos modo muchas gracias, no adjunto un ejemplo del archivo por que demasiado grande y no se que ejemplo ilustrara correctamente lo que quiero decir gracias.

Comment: @YeisonOrdoñez en todo caso un simple ejemplo basta para entender lo que quieres lograr

Answer (score 5):

Vamos a probar un pequeño truco: todo objeto `file` se comporta como un *iterador*, con el que puedes recorrer el fichero línea a línea. Para obtener el texto entre dos líneas `(n,m)` puedes usar las utilidades para iteradores del módulo `itertools`:

```
import itertools

with open("datos.txt") as data:
    texto = itertools.islice(data, n, m)

    for linea in texto:
        ....
```

Si lo que buscas son ocurrencias de `palabra` en algunas líneas:

```
import itertools

with open("datos.txt") as data:
    ocurrencias = (linea for linea in data if palabra in linea)

    for linea in ocurrencias:
        ....
```

Incluso combinar ambas:

```
import itertools

with open("datos.txt") as data:
    texto = itertools.islice(data, n, m)
    ocurrencias = (linea for linea in texto if palabra in linea)

    for linea in ocurrencias:
        ....
```

Answer (score 4):

Suponiendo tener en tu archivo `.csv` con contenido:

```
Irlanda,33°02'N,128°12'W
Rumania,33°03'N,128°25'W
Colombia,12°43'46?N,54°02'11?W
Los Angeles,34°03'N,118°15'W
Panama,40°42'46?N,74°00'21?W
Paris,48°51'24?N,2°21'03?E
Munchen,42°53'24?N,22°21'33?E
Mexico,30°42'36?N,44°00'21?W
Paris,48°51'24?N,2°21'03?E
Colombia,32°42'36?N,34°04'21?W
```

Puedes crear una funcion para extraer los registros con el contenido que deseas

```
lista = [];

def buscaPalabra(str, file):       
    for line in file:        
        for part in line.split():            
            if str in part:                
                lista.append(line);
    return lista
```

Por ejemplo al buscar "Colombia"

```
file = open('C:\Data\datos.csv','r')
print buscaPalabra("Colombia", file)
```

obtendrías las coincidencias de "Colombia":

```
['Colombia,12°43'46?N,54°02'11?W \n', 'Colombia,32°42'36?N,34°04'21?W \n']
```

Answer (score 3):

Consulta, el resultado que obtengo al buscar en un txt es lo siguiente:

```
['Usuario: carlos.lopez\r\n', 'gital<br><br>Usuario: carlos.carus<br><br>BP: 1378704 <br><br>CUIL: 2025201=\r\n']
```

lo que necesitaria es que en este caso quede en una variable carlos.lopez en otra variable 1378704 y en otra el cuil, me podran ayudar con esto?

el codigo es el siguiente:

```
    lista = [];
    file = open('archivo.txt','r')

def buscaPalabra(str, file):       
    for line in file:        
       for part in line.split():            
            if str in part:                
                lista.append(line);
    return lista
print buscaPalabra("Usuario:", file)
```