# ¿Como podria leer un fichero.txt linea a linea y pasar esos valores a a un archivo Python?

Tags: python, ftp

```
with open("login.txt") as fichero:
    dirServer = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()
    usuario = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()
    passwd = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()

datos = {}
busco = ['dirServer', 'usuario', 'passwd']

with open("login.txt") as fichero:
    for linea in fichero:
        trozos = linea.split(":")
        if trozos[0] in busco:
            datos[trozos[0]] = trozos[1].strip()

# Importa la clase FTP, necesaria para establecer una conexión, enviar y recibir datos.
from ftplib import FTP

# Se crea una instancia de dicha clase. Toma como argumentos host, user, passwd
ftp = FTP('dirServer')

# Hacemos el login de usuario y passwd, 
ftp.login(user='usuario', passwd='passwd')

# La función FTP.cwd() es utilizada para cambiar de directorio o carpeta
ftp.cwd("zzz") 

# Retorna información sobre los archivos y carpetas en la ubicación actual.
ftp.retrlines('LIST')

# Ejecuta el comando RETR para descargar el archivo README en modo binario.
# El segundo parámetro es una función callback que será llamada por cada bloque de bytes recibidos,
# que a su vez estos son pasados como argumento a dicha función. En este caso se pasa la función write de un objeto file
ftp.retrbinary('RETR prueba.txt', open('PruebaFtp.txt', 'wb').write)

ftp.quit()
```

¿Como podria pasarle el valor de ip, user, passwd desde un fichero.txt?

```
fichero.txt
dirServer: 10.0.0.4
usuario: Administrador
passwd: **********
```

me da esta serie de errores

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\My Documents\LiClipse 
Workspace\prueba2\prueba2.py", line 28, in <module>
ftp = FTP('dirServer')
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 117, in __init__
self.connect(host)
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
source_address=self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
  for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
```

socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo leer una cantidad de datos o líneas específicas en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6638/c%c3%b3mo-leer-una-cantidad-de-datos-o-l%c3%adneas-espec%c3%adficas-en-python)

Comment: Como ya te dije en en otros comentarios, que ya no están, (y empiezo a cansarme de repetir), estás mezclando en tu código las dos posibles soluciones que yo dí más abajo. Quédate con una sola (la primera). Además has puesto entre comillas los nombres de las variables, por ejemplo `FTP('dirServer')` cuando debería ser `FTP(dirServer)`.

Comment: el error que te da es que no puedes acceder a esa ip, intenta hacerle un pin a ver si le llegas; si funciona ejecuta el comando `telnet 10.0.0.4 21` si da error ya sabes que es problema de esa maquina

Comment: tengo conexion, hace ping

Comment: vale perfecto, he hecho unas modificaciones y lo he conseguido,muchas gracias por tu aporte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si el fichero tiene únicamente lo que muestras en la pregunta (no sé por qué había entendido yo inicialmente que había varios usuarios y contraseñas en el fichero), la cosa se reduce a leer las líneas y separar por donde se hallan los dos puntos.

Asumiendo que además la IP del servidor, el nombre de usuario y la contraseña aparecen exactamente en ese orden en el fichero, la cosa es trivial:

```
with open("fichero.txt") as fichero:
  servidor = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()
  usuario = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()
  clave = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()

ftp = FTP(servidor) 
ftp.login(user=usuario, passwd=clave)
ftp.cwd("zzz") 
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
ftp.retrbinary('RETR prueba.txt', open('PruebaFtp.txt', 'wb').write)
ftp.quit()
```

Es decir, una vez abierto el fichero, cada vez que uses `readline()` te devuelve una línea del mismo, sobre la cual hacemos `.split(":")` para separarlo en dos partes. Esta función devuelve una lista con las partes encontradas, y de ellas nos quedamos con la segunda (elemento `[1]` de la lista). Sobre ese valor, que será ya una cadena, hacemos `strip()` para eliminar los espacios que dicha cadena pueda tener por delante o por detrás, y el carácter de nueva línea que aparecerá al final de la misma.

Como esta solución es bastante frágil (un cambio en el orden de las líneas del fichero, o la existencia de líneas en blanco al principio o entre los elementos, haría que el programa dejara de funcionar), proporciono otro enfoque.

Se trata ahora de tener una lista con los posibles nombres de los datos en que estamos interesados en el fichero, para comparar cada línea leida con esos nombres y entonces extraer el apropiado, guardando los valores en un diccionario. Después usamos ese diccionario en la conexión FTP:

```
datos = {}
busco = ['dirServer', 'usuario', 'passwd']

with open("fichero.txt") as fichero:
  for linea in fichero:
    trozos = linea.split(":")
    if trozos[0] in busco:
      datos[trozos[0]] = trozos[1].strip()

# Verificar que hemos encontrado toda la información que queríamo
# El diccionario debe tener tantas claves como las que buscaba
if len(datos) != len(busco):
  print("El fichero no tiene el formato esperado")
else:
  ftp = FTP(datos["dirServer"])
  ftp.login(user=datos["usuario"], passwd=datos["passwd"])
  ftp.cwd("zzz") 
  ftp.retrlines('LIST')
  ftp.retrbinary('RETR prueba.txt', open('PruebaFtp.txt', 'wb').write)
  ftp.quit()
```

### Otra posibilidad

Si puedes elegir el formato del fichero con los datos, lo más correcto (y sencillo, y flexible) sería usar un formato estándar que tenga buen soporte en python. Podrías usar JSON, pero la tendencia actual es ir a otros lenguajes más fáciles de leer/escribir por humanos, como YAML o TOML.

En concreto, TOML, aunque menos conocido que otros, está ganando fuerza al ser preferido por muchos (por ser muy sencillo de parsear). Tu información guardada en un fichero TOML tendría este aspecto:

```
dirServer = '192.68.1.1'
usuario = 'abulafia'
passwd = 'secreto '
```

Y para leerlo te bastaría hacer:

```
import toml
datos = toml.decoder.load("fichero.toml")
```

y ya tendrías los datos en un diccionario. A partir de aquí seguirías como en la respuesta anterior, es decir, en `datos["username"]` tienes el nombre de usuario, etc.

Por desgracia `toml` no viene en la librería estándar python<sup>1</sup>, y tendrás que instalarlo con `pip`, pero es un módulo muy pequeño, puro python y sin dependencias.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Aunque quizás venga en el futuro porque toml ha sido elegido por la comunidad python como el lenguaje en el cual especificar los parámetros necesarios para la creación y distribución de módulos de terceros.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

{}
mi codigo queda asi:

```
with open("login.txt") as fichero:
dirServer = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()
usuario = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()
clave = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()
```

datos = {}

busco = ['dirServer', 'usuario', 'passwd']

```
with open("login.txt") as fichero:
for linea in fichero:
    trozos = linea.split(":")
    if trozos[0] in busco:
        datos[trozos[0]] = trozos[1].strip()

from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('servidor') 
ftp.login(user='usuario', passwd='clave')
ftp.cwd("zzz") 
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
ftp.retrbinary('RETR prueba.txt', open('PruebaFtp.txt', 'wb').write)
ftp.quit()
```

Me da esta serie de errores

```
 raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\prueba2\prueba2.py", line 30, in <module>
  ftp = FTP('servidor') 
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 117, in __init__
self.connect(host)
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
source_address=self.source_address)
 File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
  for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
  for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: El código que has pegado no está bien indentado. Recuerda sleccionarlo y pulsar `{}` (esto añadirá cuatro espacios por la izquierda a todas las líneas seleccionadas, lo cual es la marca para mostrarlo como código, pero cuidado que el código esté correctamente indentado según python si quitaras esos cuatro espacios). Por otro lado, ¿cuál de las soluciones usas finalmente? Parece que estás usando las dos, una tras otra. Además, veo que a `FTP()` le pasas la cadena `'servidor'`, lo que no tiene sentido. Debería ser el nombre de la variable en la que tengas lo leido del fichero

Comment: Ah, y esto no es una respuesta a la pregunta, sino una nueva pregunta... Insisto en que el formato de Stack Overflow no es de foro. Cada nueva pregunta que tengas deberías formularla como una pregunta nueva (haciendo referencia si es necesario a preguntas previas, e incorporando enlaces a ellas). La zona de respuestas es sólo para respuestas.